# Express middleware that adds custom HTML title to static files

Tags: node.js, express

Would it be possible to add a custom `<title>` to HTML pages when they are served using the `express.static('folder')` middleware?

I know that you can do the same with favicons using

https://github.com/expressjs/serve-favicon

but that only works because the browser requests the favicon itself whereas `<title>` is part of the HTML itself.

I am trying to dynamically set the title to what the content might be.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a templating engine (I like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) because it's very close to regular HTML). This would let you make a template which you pass a context to.

For a quick example, Handlebars syntax looks like this:

```
<!--template.hbs-->
<head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
```

And then on the server you would set up the following route:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    /***
    'template.hbs' - the filename of the template
    {} - the context - fill this with all the variables you 
                       want to use in your template
    ***/
    res.render('template.hbs', {title: 'My Title'});
});
```

Obviously Handlebars isn't the only templating engine available for Expressjs, here's a [page](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) from the Express docs talking about some other engines if you decide Handlebars isn't for you.

Comment: Great idea, unfortunately I have too many already written HTML files that need the dynamic `<title>`. For my next project I will certainly consider templating but for now I am looking for a patch that will keep me from touching each file.

Comment: @ThatBrianDudeYou could try ejs then. You would not need to change html files then

Comment: I dont see how using ejs would help me in my situation. It still requres the HTML files to be written with its own syntax.